# What is the best Legendary augment for a Monk in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

For one of the season 12 Objective, I have to augment a legendary item in Kanai's Cube. I would like to augment an item for my monk. I'm currently using the [Sunwuko Build from icyvines](https://www.icy-veins.com/d3/monk-sunwuko-wave-of-light-build-patch-2-6-1-season-12), and it's working pretty well.

I have three questions:

- What item should I augment to get the most power? And what gems to go along with it? (most important!)
- What level should the legendary gem be before sacrificing it? Level 80?
- Can I augment the item to have more than one legendary gem? For example, if I augment with Legendary Gem A, then later augment with Legendary Gem B, would that net me both benefits in that one augmented item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As for what items to augment first**, it doesn't really matter, but in general you should augment items with better rolls. You are already using icy veins guides, so on this page [Gear reccomentadion](https://www.icy-veins.com/d3/sunwuko-wave-of-light-monk-bis-gear-gems-paragon-points) you can see desired rolls for all your items. If you have ancient items with good rolls - go for it, it doesn't matter if it's weapon or some other slot.

**As for gem level**, for season journey it's required to do augmentation of at least 50 level gem. Each gem level will give you 5 points of primary stat, so if you sacrifice level 100 gem you will receive bonus of 500 primary stat. The gem itself doesn't matter, you can use any legendary gem. Attribute is chosen by Flawless Royal gems which are required for recipe as well. For Monks, I think, dexterity is preferable stat, so use Flawless Royal Emeralds.

**As for multiple augmentation**, you can augment item more than once, but only the latest augmentation will be effective. High level augmentation makes sense only if you are going to push higher greater rifts.

Comment: oh okay, so the legendary gem doesn't transfer its benefits over to the weapon, it only just add +5 to the primary stat of the weapon per level? Like, if I use the legendary gem that gives xp, then the sword I put it on won't get the xp bonus if I augment it with this gem?

Comment: @shelfpick yes, augmentation will only add primary stat of choice to item

Answer (score 1):

1. Doesn't really matter, most people start with weapon and add their primary stat. For you that would be emeralds because of Dex.
2. The gem requirements are down below. It doesn't really matter what level it is, the higher obviously being better though. Don't kill yourself trying to get another 2 levels, it's not worth the time investment if you can't do it quickly.
3. No. Once you use the legendary Gem to upgrade an ancient item, you'll have to level a same legendary Gem from rank zero.

Legendary gem requirement:

Level 30+ for weapons

Level 40+ for rings and amulets

Level 50+ for armour including shields, quivers, and sources.